# chrome extensions with jqueryui error for dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I seem to be getting the error:

`Error in event handler for contextMenus: TypeError: undefined is not a function at context_menu_onClick (sample.js line 21)`

My manifest.json file is

```
{
  "name": "Wikipedia",
  "description": "Just testing",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "https://*/", "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js","jquery.min.js","jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"]
  },
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "css": ["jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://en.wikipedia.org; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I think that everything is fine on this front. Here is an excerpt of my sample.js file and the error location:

```
function context_menu_onClick(info, tab) {
alert('This is a dialog box using jqueryui');
var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog"><p>This is your dialog content, which can be multiline and dynamic.</p></div>');
NewDialog.dialog({ //<---- ERROR HERE
modal: true,
title: "title",
show: 'clip',
hide: 'clip',
buttons: [
    {text: "Submit", click: function() {doSomething()}},
    {text: "Cancel", click: function() {$(this).dialog("close")}}
]
});
```

My mission is that when `context_menu_onClick` happens that a user is prompted with a jqueryUI dialog box... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `dialog` method like simple substitution for `alert`. `$(this).dialog("close");` should work in this way `$( /* DOM node you want to turn into a dialog */ ).dialog( /* dialog options */ );` Also to have dialog method available, you need jQuery UI version 1.0 or later, and jQuery Update adds 1.8.11. See this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94948/jquery-ui-dialog-does-not-work

Comment: @Danny did you get this to work ? I'm running into same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `manifest.json` file, more precisely in your `"background"` field: **you are declaring the `sample.js` script before the `jquery-ui.min.js` script**. This will result in an error if you try to create some UI parts using jQuery, because your script runs before jQuery gets initialized.

To solve this, just reorder the scripts in your background:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "jquery.min.js",
        "jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "sample.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I didn't know order mattered in this instance. I made the change to my file yet I still get the same error

Comment: @Danny Well, have you reloaded your extension? Besides, creating the UI in the invisible background page won't do anything. Read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). I already told you to do that by the way.